# HttpURLConnection response shows as Unauthorized

Tags: java

Background:

We have a Desktop Java based app which calls an ASPX page hosted in a different server which doesn't need authentication.

Trials done:

- I found this app started getting unauthorized/401 after JRE updated to 1.8.0_201; When I switch this back to JRE 1.8.0_141 everything works fine.
- I have fired the same using RESTClient; I see that the request has been sent to the website.

  Code example:

  ```
   //Create connection      
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
             "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out;
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());     
        out.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n");
        out.write("<methodCall>\r\n");
        out.write("  <project>" + "<![CDATA["+"Pla"+"]]>" + "</project>\r\n");
        out.write("</methodCall>\r\n");
  ```

Exact error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?

---

Below is some content for both JREs:
JRE_1.8.0_201:
**Mar 27, 2019 1:20:45 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getServerAuthentication
FINER: Server Authentication for AuthenticationHeader: prefer NTLM returned null**

JRE_1.8.0_131:
ar 27, 2019 11:28:35 AM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getServerAuthentication
**FINER: Server Authentication for AuthenticationHeader: prefer NTLM returned sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthentication@728938a9**
Mar 27, 2019 11:28:35 AM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect0

Comment: *server which doesnt need authentication* - then where does the 401 come from?

Comment: yes as said, nothing was changed in Server. With only JRE Update this issue is popped up.

Comment: @chandra - to be clear - EVERYTHING stays the same - NOTHING changes - except the JRE version? Then it must be something related to the JRE: did the User-Agent header value change? That might be causing a WAF (e.g. mod_security) error to be propagated back up. Can you use tcpdump/wireshark to see what's going on the wire with both JREs?

Comment: i have never used User-Agent in my request? What shall be the value for Java Desktop application

Comment: If you are not using Authorization in your server this error would be thrown if you haven't set a CORS filter on the server. For debugging you can get the input error stream  and read the errors like this:

`InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connect.getErrorStram());
`

Comment: updated the request for both JREs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the value of the User-Agent header. Try setting it to "Mozilla/5.0" for example.

Comment: Could you capture the complete request and response for both JRE's and compare the contents?

Comment: I have updated the response for both JREs and see NTLM Authentication is returned NULL in case and other some value

Comment: BTW it seems you 'upgraded' to an older version of the JRE. 1.8.0_141 works fine, 1.8.0_201 gives the 401. Why don't you continue with the 141 version?

Comment: The server seems to use NTLM authentication. Could it be you are hitting this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151788 ?

Comment: I have switched to Apache libraries rather than using Java urlconnection.

Answer (score 0):

We've had a similar problem with HttpURLConnection and this specific 1.8.0_201 jre with failing authentication and a "Authentication: Basic xxyyy" header. 
Our scenario was that the server first answered with a "301 moved permanently" and the httpurlconnection correctly retried the request with the new provided url, but the "Authentication" header was missing so we ran against a 401.

Fun fact: When setting the the header like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization ", "Basic " + authString);
```

(see the additional space after the header name) it worked, so I believe the filter for the "Authentication" header is a intended behaviour, and bad implemented ;-)